# pass previous index to spinner's onItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, spinner, listener

I am using a spinner in my application. After selecting an index in spinner I open

a new activity and then come back to the first. Now my spinner is showing the previous selected value and if I select the same index again nothing happens.

The doc says `onItemSelectedListener` invokes iff the index is different from the previous. And I can't set it to default(0) when i come back.

So is there any alternative solution to do this? Please help me. Thanks. Here is my code:

```
companyspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                    android.view.View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Object o = companyspin.getSelectedItem();
                network = CheckNetworkStateReceiver.isOnline(context);
                selectCompany = o.toString().trim();
                Data.homeCommunityValue = arg2;
                setCompanyList(arg2);
                flagCatageory = false;
                try {
                    tracker.trackEvent("Home", // Category
                            "Drop Down Selection", // Action
                            selectCompany, // Label
                            arg2); // Value
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });``
```

Comment: is there any other way istead of creating a custom spinner??

Comment: do you want to set it default ?

Comment: Could you please post a code sample? How did you try to set it to default?

Comment: You can use ListView instead of spinner...

Comment: i am not saying that i cant , i mean the condition is that in which i cant set it to default . :)

Comment: Can you post your code ? So we can help you.

Comment: can anyone post code for custom spinner??

Answer (score 0):

You start the new activity as soon as it's selected in the spinner ?

Just grab the data from the spinner you need for your activity in the onItemSele.... listener.
Set
 `mySpinner.setSelection(your_position)`

before your new activity starts. If you want it to stay the on the same value in the spinner, a Button to activate your selection seems easier, and less error-prone for the user depending on what the selection do.

EDIT:
The selection is still the same afterwards so the callback will never fire. You can put a placebo object at position(0) with some info text "Choose here..." which you can return to after a valid selection, with setSelection. Just add a check in the listener if it's a valid choice or the placebo.

Comment: But my condition is not manually set the spinner , it already shows the selected and again i want to select the same index which i've selected before.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want 1st item to be selected when you return to your main activity, you can try

```
companyspin.setSelection(0);
```

in `onCreate()` of main activity.